# Why view render "1" before checked radio button

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I check radio button with value from database, it works, but it has rendered "1" just before that checked radio button. If I remove if statement then it does't show.

```
<?php $formUserType = UserType::all(); ?>

@foreach($formUserType as $valUT)
  {{ $varSetRadio = false }}

  @if($user->profile->dic_user_type_id == $valUT->id)
    {{ $varSetRadio = true }}
  @endif

  {!! Form::radio('profile[dic_user_type_id]', $valUT->id, $varSetRadio) !!} {{ $valUT->name }}
  <br />
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ expr }}` translates to `<?php echo e(expr) ?>`.

The output of an assignment is the rightmost value in php, so `($var = 1)` is equal to 1 (Also `true` is equal to 1 because PHP is truthy)

Do the following:

```
@foreach($formUserType as $value)
    {!! Form::radio('profile[dic_user_type_id]', $value->id, $user->profile->dic_user_type_id === $value->id) !!}
    {{ $value->name }}
  <br />
@endforeach
```

In addition, you shouldn't be comparing anything but simple logic in a view.

Try adding the comparison for `dic_user_type` to the `User` model itself, and pass your data in instead of fetching outside of a controller/model.